# some characters lose formatting in vba macro others don't

Tags: vba, unicode, ms-word, macros

I have a number of documents that are made in the pre-Unicode era, and contain transcriptions of various languages, each with their own fonts. 
I made a macro that replaces every character in a document with another character (from multiple old transcription fonts into a unicode font). (see code below of the macro for one of these fonts)

For some reason, the macro keeps the formatting (in my case, mostly italics) for some characters, not for others. This leaves me with a lot of words in which some letters are italicized, and other letters aren't, e.g.

*al-Malik al-Mu*ǧā*hid ḫu*ṭ*ba*

The characters that lose the formatting are all characters with diacritics, but not all characters with diacritics lose their formatting (e.g., the ḫ in the example). 
Not all characters that keep their formatting have the same code point in the original font as in the unicode font (e.g., the ḫ in the example has unicode number U+23 in the original font and U+1E2B in the unicode font).

Do you have an idea why the formatting is kept for some characters, and not for others? Or how I could solve this problem?

Alternatively, I could add another macro to the procedure that would format all words that contain at least one letter in italics into italics (but how to do that is another question: [MS Word macro to correct partially formatted words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739331/ms-word-macro-to-correct-partially-formatted-words)).

```
Sub BatchReplaceAOTimes()

'Replace the font AO Times New Roman in the body and footnotes
'of the active document

Debug.Print "Replacing AO Times New Roman font"
Dim old_values(270) As String
Dim unicode_values(270) As Long

old_values(0) = &H30
old_values(1) = &H31
(...)
old_values(263) = &HFD
old_values(264) = &HDD
old_values(265) = &H178
old_values(266) = &HFF
old_values(267) = &H5A
old_values(268) = &H7A
old_values(269) = &H2C
old_values(270) = &H9

unicode_values(0) = &H30
unicode_values(1) = &H31
(...)
unicode_values(263) = &H2BE
unicode_values(264) = &H2BF
unicode_values(265) = &H1E6E
unicode_values(267) = &H5A
unicode_values(268) = &H7A
unicode_values(269) = &H2C
unicode_values(270) = &H9

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

Dim ThisRng As Range

'do body text
Set ThisRng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
For i = 0 To 270
    Debug.Print i

    ThisRng.Find.ClearFormatting
    ThisRng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With ThisRng.Find
        .Font.Name = "AO Times New Roman"
        .Text = ChrW(old_values(i))
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(unicode_values(i))
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    ThisRng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next i

   (...: do the same for the footnotes)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, just as a suggestion, you could have a smaller code base if you set the array as: -

```
Dim ValueMap(270)  As String
Dim AryTemp()      As String
ValueMap(0) = "&H30|&H30"

For i = 0 To 270
    AryTemp = Split(ValueMap(i),"|")
    'AryTemp(0) = The Old
    'AryTemp(1) = The New
Next
```

As to an answer to your question. I am unaware of how to stop it losing the italic, I suspect this could be caused by it being set to italic via a style instead of formatting or vice versa, but that depth of investigation would not fit in this environment (Q&A) I don't think.

As for a solution, there are many ways to do what you need to, as solutioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739331/ms-word-macro-to-correct-partially-formatted-words), I don't think this can be done in a blanket manner (i.e. there is no way to set all those that were italic back to italic in one go) as the information is not retained after the find and replace is executed. So it would have to be done at the point the character is swapped, meaning it can only do one find and replace at a time which will have a performance impact.

In the below example I have also used the shorter array method described above.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim BlnWasItalic        As Boolean
Dim AryValueMap(270)    As String
Dim AryTemp()           As String
Dim LngLocation         As Long
Dim LngValueID          As Long
Dim WdDoc               As Word.Document
Dim WdFnd               As Word.Find
Dim WdRng               As Word.Range
Dim WdSlct              As Word.Selection

AryValueMap(0) = "&H30|&H30"
AryValueMap(1) = "&H31|&H31"
'...
AryValueMap(269) = "&H2C|H2C"
AryValueMap(270) = "&H9|&H9"

Set WdDoc = ThisDocument
    For Each WdRng In WdDoc.StoryRanges
        For LngValueID = 0 To 270
            WdRng.Select
            Set WdSlct = Selection
                WdSlct.SetRange 0, 0
                Set WdFnd = WdSlct.Find

                    'Clear any previous find settings
                    If LngValueID = 0 Then
                        WdFnd.ClearAllFuzzyOptions
                        WdFnd.ClearFormatting
                        WdFnd.ClearHitHighlight

                        .Font.Name = "AO Times New Roman"

                    End If

                    AryTemp = Split(AryValueMap(LngValueID), "|")

                    'Look for any italic character
                    Do Until Not WdFnd.Execute(FindText:=ChrW(AryTemp(0)), MatchCase:=True, _
                                                MatchWholeWord:=False, MatchWildcards:=False, _
                                                MatchSoundsLike:=False, MatchAllWordForms:=False, _
                                                Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop, Format:=True, _
                                                ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceNone, _
                                                MatchKashida:=False, MatchDiacritics:=False, _
                                                MatchAlefHamza:=False, MatchControl:=False)

                        'Take note if it was italic
                        BlnWasItalic = WdSlct.Font.Italic

                        'Make the replacement
                        WdSlct = ChrW(AryTemp(1))

                        'Remember the location (in case there are due to be more than
                        'one change in one word
                        LngLocation = WdSlct.End

                        'Expand the selection to the whole word
                        WdSlct.Expand wdWord

                        'Set the font
                        WdSlct.Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"

                        'Set the word to be italic if it was meant to be
                        WdSlct.Font.Italic = BlnWasItalic

                        'Move past the word
                        WdSlct.SetRange LngLocation, LngLocation
                    Loop
                Set WdFnd = Nothing
            Set WdSlct = Nothing
            DoEvents
        Next
        DoEvents
    Next
Set WdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

(This code is untested and formed to exemplify a solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning AutoCorrect off as that can replace some characters.

In Word characters have Paragraph style and character style, so you can try looking into those:

```
Debug.Print ThisRng.Style.Description
Debug.Print ThisRng.CharacterStyle.Description
Debug.Print ThisRng.ParagraphStyle.Description
```